# Calculating angles between 2 lines.

Tags: geometry

Suppose there are two lines:
    1. $y_1=a_1x+b_1$
    2. $y_2=a_2x+b_2$
then the angle between them is $\lvert \arctan(a_1)-\arctan(a_2)\rvert$, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

$$
\tan \theta = \tan(A-B) = \frac{\tan(A)-\tan(B)}{1+\tan(A)\tan(B)} =
\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1\cdot m_2}.
$$

---

For additional information:

http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/68285.html

related to your question about signs,there is more information

http://planetmath.org/anglebetweentwolines

yes  you are right,there is absolute sign

Comment: There's something I don't understand in your formula, what if I get a negative numbers, when subtracting m2 from m1? The angle between 2 line should always be positive, so should there be a absloute value sign for m1-m2 term?

Comment: see please update

Comment: is there any unclear  part  ?if yes  you could ask me

Comment: Thanks for caring about my question, but I need to go to bed, laters.